why is my media screen and radio quit working after i start my 2016 lexus rx 350
When I start my Lexus. The media display screen turns on and the Lexus logo comes on the screen. Looks perfectly fine but after everything started up. The display screen then goes black and blank. And my radio or my media will not work. My rear camera works. Its also the screen use for the front camera,which dont work. I can get no picture on it or no media as far as radio or anything else like that to work after I start my car.

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! :o)
